# Pass AJAX param and access it from expressjs side of application

Tags: html, node.js, ajax, express

I feel like I am missing something here.
To start, you have an AJAX call you can do in  tag to post data to the backend, which looks something like,

```
function changeDom(){
         console.log('connecting');
          $.ajax({
                   url: '/loadOrders',
                   method:'POST'
                 }).done(function(data){
                     if(data.success){
                         $('#recentOrders').append(data.message);
                         changeDom2();
                         return;
                     }
                 }).fail(function(){
                     console.log('failed');
                     return;
                 });
         };
```

And on the backend you receive it with code that looks something like,

```
app.post('/loadOrders', function(req,response)
{  // code here });
```

I have seen that it is possible to pass a parameter along an AJAX call, which looks like,

```
$.ajax({
                   url: '/loadOrders',
                   method:'POST',
                   data: {field1: 'this is data being passed'}
                 }).done(function(data){}});
```

But how would I receive that data on the backend? How would that change in syntax look and how would I call the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by doing

```
req.body.field1
```